# Formula in excel to increment by percentage X number of times

Tags: excel, math

I have a pretty simple problem I am trying to solve, but can't figure it out and can't even think of what to put in google.

I have two cells in excel.  One (A1) will have a number, say from 0-100.  In the other (A2) I want to start with 15 when A1 is 0, and increment by 15% for each increase in A1.  Here is what should show at various points:

A1 -   A2
0 -    15
1 -   17.25
2 -   19.8375
3 -   22.81313
...
10 -   60.68337
...
20 -  245.4981

and so on... Basically in this form it is just the cell above * 1.15.  But I can't figure out how to condense that into a single formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a more "standard" spreadsheet nomenclature:

```
   |     A           B
---+-----------+-----------
 1 |         0          15
 2 |         1       17.25
 3 |         2     19.8375
```

If you just want the cell to be 15% more than the cell above it, put in (for example) `B2`:

```
= B1 * 1.15
```

and copy that to all other `B` cells below `B2`.

If you want it based on `An` (if, for example, the `A` cells may not be consecutive), you can use powers (again in `B2`):

```
= B$1 * (1.15 ^ A2)
```

though I'm wasn't *entirely* sure if `^` is the exponentiation operator in Excel, I've long since switched to Gnumeric. A quick web search seems to indicate that it is the correct operator.

Comment: I got that, but my question revolves around having everything in just two cells, so that as I change A1, A2 changes.

Comment: @bhouse, see the update, you can use powers to make it dependent on your `A1` column.